# How to execute while controller with the same count as Number Of threads under the Thread Plan

Tags: while-loop, controller, jmeter, threadgroup

I want to iterate my entire thread plan with certain number of threads. My Thread plan consists of Include Controller, few Samplers and While controller which is fetching data from CSV data config. 
Where do I need provide the Number of Threads so that my while loop also iterates that many times?

I added Number of Threads as 10 in the main thread group, so the Include controller and other HTTP sampler are getting iterated 10 times. But it doesn't iterate while loop 10 times. It executes only once.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKiJM.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGHTI.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace While Controller with the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller)
2. Use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as the condition:

   ```
   ${__groovy(ctx.getThreadGroup().getNumThreads(),)}
   ```

   in the above expression `ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class instance which provides access to all thread (virtual user) context information. Check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) article for more details on JMeter API shortcuts available for [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and __groovy() function
3. That's it, now the Loop Controller will iterate as many times as the number of threads (virtual users) defined in the Thread Group. Remember that it will be **per thread**, i.e. if you have 10 threads the Loop Controller's children will be executed 100 times.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. 
However, can you help me to suggest how to proceed ahead with step-2.
I am unable to add condition in loop controller, like while controller. 
Can you please suggest, how can I achieve this.

Also, I have a condition for while logic to fetch data from CSV, and iterate the samplers . 
Is It possible to add both the condition in Loop Controller?

Answer (score 0):

I got a simple solution for the same, by setting CSV Data Config of while controller to Current Thread instead of A